# Let $G=(\Bbb Z^*_{15},·)$. I want to find multiple properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I have to find a lot of information on this.  I know by the euler function $$φ(15)=φ(5\cdot 3)=5\cdot 3\bigg(1-\frac{1}{5}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{1}{3}\bigg)=8$$  So I have: $$(\Bbb Z^*_{15},·)=\{[1], [2], [4], [7], [8], [11], [13], [14]\}$$Since all these elements are relatively prime.  I got the orders of all these elements with $$ord([1])=1$$$$ord([2])=4$$$$ord([4])=2$$$$ord([7])=x$$$$ord([8])=4$$$$ord([11])=2$$$$ord([13])=4$$$$ord([14])=2$$  The only one I couldn't get was $[7]$ because I couldn't rearrange the others into something made of $7$, can somebody explain to me how to get $ord([7])$.  Also correct if I am wrong but this group is not cyclic.  I believe it so not...

Comment: I’m confused. Is not $\Bbb Z_{14}^\times$ the congruence classes modulo $14$ that are relatively prime to $14$? If so, any computation of $\phi(15)$ is not relevant.

Comment: I meant 15 just fixed it!

Comment: You mean $\Bbb{Z}_{15}^\times$, not $\Bbb{Z}_{14}^\times$. To get the order of $7$, just keeping taking powers, and modding by $15$. $7^2 = 49 = 4$, and then $7^3 = 4 \cdot 7 = 28 = 13$, and then $7^4 = 13*7 = 91 = 1$. So the order is $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it is not cyclic. This is because the order of all non-identity elements are either $2$ or $4$. If it were cyclic, there would have to be an element of order $\varphi(15) = 8$, which there is not.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't cyclic because $15$ is not $1,2,4,p^k$ or $2p^k$ for $p$ an odd prime.   Cyclicity of $\Bbb Z_n^×$ is equivalent to $n$ being a number of said form.  (Gauß knew that.)